# XLST Group multiple order items into new group child node based on same invoice ID

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm struggling with the XSLT to transform an XML containing orders. I have an XML where I have all order lines as separate elements, where Invoice ID is the identifier of the order, something like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ORDERS05>
   <ORDER>
      <CUSTCODE>ZSO005</CUSTCODE>
      <CUSTNAME>Customer 1</CUSTNAME>
      <TRANSDATE>5/6/23</TRANSDATE>
      <INVNO>30722</INVNO>
      <CUSTOMERREFNO>1</CUSTOMERREFNO>
      <PRODUCTCODE>1</PRODUCTCODE>
      <DESCRIPTION>BRONZE</DESCRIPTION>
      <QUANTITY>42</QUANTITY>
      <PRICE>177</PRICE>
      <VAT>35</VAT>
      <UNITCOST>2</UNITCOST>
      <LINECOST>387</LINECOST>
      <ADJ>86</ADJ>
      <VAT>3</VAT>
      <NET>990</NET>
      <TOTALVAT>198</TOTALVAT>
      <CUSTTYPE>Account</CUSTTYPE>
      <CONSIGNMENTNO>5/6/23</CONSIGNMENTNO>
      <TRANSTYPE>CR</TRANSTYPE>
      <LINENO>1</LINENO>
      <CURRENCYCODE>GBP</CURRENCYCODE>
   </ORDER>
   <ORDER>
      <CUSTCODE>ZSO005</CUSTCODE>
      <CUSTNAME>Customer 1</CUSTNAME>
      <TRANSDATE>5/6/23</TRANSDATE>
      <INVNO>30722</INVNO>
      <CUSTOMERREFNO>1</CUSTOMERREFNO>
      <PRODUCTCODE>2</PRODUCTCODE>
      <DESCRIPTION>GOLD</DESCRIPTION>
      <QUANTITY>4</QUANTITY>
      <PRICE>179</PRICE>
      <VAT>35</VAT>
      <UNITCOST>2</UNITCOST>
      <LINECOST>387</LINECOST>
      <ADJ>86</ADJ>
      <VAT>3</VAT>
      <NET>990</NET>
      <TOTALVAT>198</TOTALVAT>
      <CUSTTYPE>Account</CUSTTYPE>
      <CONSIGNMENTNO>5/6/23</CONSIGNMENTNO>
      <TRANSTYPE>CR</TRANSTYPE>
      <LINENO>2</LINENO>
      <CURRENCYCODE>GBP</CURRENCYCODE>
   </ORDER>
   <ORDER>
      <CUSTCODE>ZSO005</CUSTCODE>
      <CUSTNAME>Customer 1</CUSTNAME>
      <TRANSDATE>5/6/23</TRANSDATE>
      <INVNO>30735</INVNO>
      <CUSTOMERREFNO>1</CUSTOMERREFNO>
      <PRODUCTCODE>1</PRODUCTCODE>
      <DESCRIPTION>BRONZE</DESCRIPTION>
      <QUANTITY>42</QUANTITY>
      <PRICE>177</PRICE>
      <VAT>£35</VAT>
      <UNITCOST>2</UNITCOST>
      <LINECOST>387</LINECOST>
      <ADJ>86</ADJ>
      <VAT>3</VAT>
      <NET>990</NET>
      <TOTALVAT>198</TOTALVAT>
      <CUSTTYPE>Account</CUSTTYPE>
      <CONSIGNMENTNO>5/6/23</CONSIGNMENTNO>
      <TRANSTYPE>CR</TRANSTYPE>
      <LINENO>1</LINENO>
      <CURRENCYCODE>GBP</CURRENCYCODE>
   </ORDER>
</ORDERS05>
```

I want to transform this XML, so I combine all items that are on the same order (based on INVNO id) to be moved into new PRODUCTS element and then assigned to LINEITEM each, like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ORDERS05>
   <ORDER>
      <CUSTCODE>ZSO005</CUSTCODE>
      <CUSTNAME>Customer 1</CUSTNAME>
      <TRANSDATE>5/6/23</TRANSDATE>
      <INVNO>30722</INVNO>
      <CUSTOMERREFNO>1</CUSTOMERREFNO>
      <PRODUCTS>
        <LINEITEM>
         <PRODUCTCODE>1</PRODUCTCODE>
         <DESCRIPTION>BRONZE</DESCRIPTION>
         <QUANTITY>42</QUANTITY>
         <PRICE>177</PRICE>
         <VAT>35</VAT>
         <UNITCOST>2</UNITCOST>
         <LINECOST>387</LINECOST>
         <ADJ>86</ADJ>
         <VAT>3</VAT>
         <NET>990</NET>
         <TOTALVAT>198</TOTALVAT>
         <CUSTTYPE>Account</CUSTTYPE>
         <CONSIGNMENTNO>5/6/23</CONSIGNMENTNO>
         <TRANSTYPE>CR</TRANSTYPE>
         <LINENO>1</LINENO>
         <CURRENCYCODE>GBP</CURRENCYCODE>
       </LINEITEM>
       <LINEITEM>
         <PRODUCTCODE>2</PRODUCTCODE>
         <DESCRIPTION>GOLD</DESCRIPTION>
         <QUANTITY>4</QUANTITY>
         <PRICE>179</PRICE>
         <VAT>35</VAT>
         <UNITCOST>2</UNITCOST>
         <LINECOST>387</LINECOST>
         <ADJ>86</ADJ>
         <VAT>3</VAT>
         <NET>990</NET>
         <TOTALVAT>198</TOTALVAT>
         <CUSTTYPE>Account</CUSTTYPE>
         <CONSIGNMENTNO>5/6/23</CONSIGNMENTNO>
         <TRANSTYPE>CR</TRANSTYPE>
         <LINENO>2</LINENO>
         <CURRENCYCODE>GBP</CURRENCYCODE>
       </LINEITEM>
      </PRODUCTS>
   </ORDER>
   <ORDER>
      <CUSTCODE>ZSO005</CUSTCODE>
      <CUSTNAME>Customer 1</CUSTNAME>
      <TRANSDATE>5/6/23</TRANSDATE>
      <INVNO>30735</INVNO>
      <CUSTOMERREFNO>1</CUSTOMERREFNO>
      <PRODUCTS>
       <LINEITEM>
        <PRODUCTCODE>1</PRODUCTCODE>
        <DESCRIPTION>BRONZE</DESCRIPTION>
        <QUANTITY>42</QUANTITY>
        <PRICE>177</PRICE>
        <VAT>35</VAT>
        <UNITCOST>2</UNITCOST>
        <LINECOST>387</LINECOST>
        <ADJ>86</ADJ>
        <VAT>3</VAT>
        <NET>990</NET>
        <TOTALVAT>198</TOTALVAT>
        <CUSTTYPE>Account</CUSTTYPE>
        <CONSIGNMENTNO>5/6/23</CONSIGNMENTNO>
        <TRANSTYPE>CR</TRANSTYPE>
        <LINENO>1</LINENO>
        <CURRENCYCODE>GBP</CURRENCYCODE>
       </LINEITEM>
      <PRODUCTS>
    </ORDER>
</ORDERS05>
```

Could you please help me with the XSLT? I'm quite new to it, I tried to search for some solutions, but didn't find anything that was fitting my requirement.

Thanks.

Comment: See the info section in [tag:xslt-grouping]

Comment: Hopefully you'll find an answer among those linked by Martin, but please note in particular the advice that grouping is much easier in XSLT 2.0 than in 1.0, so you need to decide whether you are able to use a 2.0 processor.